# Getting the correct order of output with append in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` in which I want to place column 1 under colum 0 and column 2 under column 1 and so on for `n` number of columns so that I have one series.

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Adf', 'Bdf', 'Cdf','Ddf','Edf','Fdf','Gdf'],[45.1, 34.3, 23.1,67.1,45.4,78.2,85.1]] ) 
tmp = pd.Series([], dtype=object)
for i in range(df.shape[1]-1):
    tmp=tmp.append(df.iloc[:][i].append(df.iloc[:][i+1]))
```

Output:`df`

```
      0     1     2     3     4     5     6
0   Adf   Bdf   Cdf   Ddf   Edf   Fdf   Gdf
1  45.1  34.3  23.1  67.1  45.4  78.2  85.1
```

Output: `tmp`: Almost correct but there are double entries

```
0     Adf
1    45.1
0     Bdf
1    34.3
0     Bdf
1    34.3
0     Cdf
1    23.1
0     Cdf
1    23.1
0     Ddf
1    67.1
0     Ddf
1    67.1
0     Edf
1    45.4
0     Edf
1    45.4
0     Fdf
1    78.2
0     Fdf
1    78.2
0     Gdf
1    85.1
```

Desired Output:Created manually

```
Adf
45.1
Bdf
34.3
Cdf
23.1
Ddf
67.1
Edf
45.4
Fdf
78.2
Gdf
85.1
```

I welcome any better approaches. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
s = df.unstack().reset_index(drop=True)
print (s)
0      Adf
1     45.1
2      Bdf
3     34.3
4      Cdf
5     23.1
6      Ddf
7     67.1
8      Edf
9     45.4
10     Fdf
11    78.2
12     Gdf
13    85.1
dtype: object
```

Or convert all values to numpy array and then use [`np.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
s = pd.Series(np.ravel(df.to_numpy().T))
print (s)
0      Adf
1     45.1
2      Bdf
3     34.3
4      Cdf
5     23.1
6      Ddf
7     67.1
8      Edf
9     45.4
10     Fdf
11    78.2
12     Gdf
13    85.1
dtype: object
```